# How to ensure a target is run before all the other build rules in a makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have a C++ project which contains a generated file that all the other C++ files depend on. I'm trying to force that file to be generated and compiled before any other compilation begins. Usually it'd be as simple as putting that file first in the `all:` target, but the complication is that my Makefile is also generated by a build system, and I can only append fragments to the Makefile, not edit it in general.

So, is there a way to force that generated file target to run first, via dependencies or otherwise? I've thought of using something like this:

```
cpp_files := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
$(cpp_files): generated_file.cpp
generated_file.cpp:
    # generate the file here
```

But it doesn't seem to work. For reference, my source dir structure is like this, so I need to collect the cpp files recursively:

```
src/
|---file1.cpp
|---file2.cpp
|---subdir1/
    |---file3.cpp

gen/
|---generated_file.cpp
```

Answer (score 26):

If you're sure that's really what you want, here's one way to do it: have a rule for a dummy file which the makefile will `include`.

```
.PHONY: dummy
dummy:
    # generate the file here

-include dummy
```

No matter what target you specify, Make will first run the `dummy` rule, then restart itself.

Comment: Wonderful! This is a true life saver!

Comment: Note: if you have other includes which are depending on generated files, then dummy include must *follow* these includes, not precede as you might think.

Comment: The last comment by @stunpix was really a saver for me. It made a difference with Cygwin make, thanks!

Comment: Can we rely on this kind of trick? After all if `GNUmake` would completely follow its own documentation, the connection between a real file and a `PHONY` target should not exist.

Comment: @Vroomfondel: The GNUMake documentation does not make such a broad promise.

Comment: [PHONY](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets): "to avoid conflict with a file of the same name" ... I can't help but read this as "whatever you do with the real file it will have no effect on the rule with that name", thus nulling the usual `make` promise of looking at the target file date before executing the rule. That said, couldn't we simply drop `PHONY` alltogether in this case? [The docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles) are explicit in that `make` will first remake any real include file before doing anything else, no?

Comment: @Vroomfondel: It's pretty specific about the conflict that `.PHONY` will prevent, namely exempting the rule from the very promise you cite. But there can still be a connection between the file and the rule, e.g. 1) if the makefile `includes` the file, Make will execute the rule. 2) If the makefile `includes` the file, and the file exists, its contents might abort the Make process before the execution of the rule, and 3) the behavior of the commands in the recipe might depend on the contents of the file (or whether the file exists). The trick is fairly reliable but not unbreakable.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, other `cpp` files don't depend on the generated one (in terms of Make rules). Dependency graph still looks like:

```
program
 |
 ^- file1.o
 |   ^- file1.c
 |
 ^- file2.o
 |   ^- file2.c
 |
 ^- generated_file.o
     ^- generated_file.c
         ^- <generator prerequisites>
```

Your source files could only depend on some kind of generated header file (in case when it is `#include`d by these sources).

If you need to generate only a `cpp` file then the following makefile should be sufficient:

```
srcs := $(wildcard src/*.cpp src/*/*.cpp)

gen_file := gen/generated_file.cpp
srcs += $(gen_file)

objs := $(srcs:.cpp=.o)

.PHONY : all
all : program

program : $(objs)
    @$(LD) ...

%.o : %.c
    @$(CC) ...

$(gen_file) :
    # generate the file here
```

### UPD.

A little improvement based on [Beta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10727593/545027).

```
-include generator-task
.PHONY : generator-task

generator-task : $(gen_files)

$(gen_files) : $(gen_prerequisites)
    # generate the file here
```

Instead of running generator on each invocation of Make, this will only regenerate a file when one of its prerequisites would change.

Comment: Actually, I do have a generated header as well as the `cpp` file. Would the code you provided be much different then?

Comment: @andrei, rather yes than no... In that case I would suggest you to split the code generation and compilation phases. Actually, Beta's solution achieves the same goal.