# See output of shell script in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How can I execute a shell script before building my targets in a Makefile, and see the output as it runs?

I have a script called `prepare.sh` that generates a bunch of .pyx files.
The .pyx files are the starting point of my build process involving make.
It goes from .pyx -> .c -> .o -> .so

I don't like having to run prepare.sh separately prior to make.  I'd like make to run it for me.

I got it to work but I don't see the output of the command.  I'd like to see it.  This is what I have now:

```
PATH := ${PYTHONHOME}/bin:${PATH}

NOTHING:=$(shell ./prepare.sh)

PYXS?=$(wildcard merged/*.pyx)
SOURCES=$(PYXS:.pyx=.c)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
SOBJECTS=$(OBJECTS:.o=.so)
```

Comment: you could just call the 'make' command in `prepare.sh`.  or you could completely separate them and use `./prepare.sh && make`, all you have to do then is hit up (in most shells) to recall the command.

Answer (score 6):

Redirect the output of your script to stderr. In this case you also can get rid of dummy `NOTHING` variable:

```
$(shell ./prepare.sh >&2)
```

### UPD.

Another option is to execute the script inside a recipe which runs prior to everithing else:

```
.PHONY : prepare
prepare :
    ./prepare.sh

-include prepare
```

See also: the original Beta's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10727593/545027) with this hack, GNU Make manual [entry](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles) explaining how it works.