# make implicit rule with force vs .phony

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Can someone shed light on the difference here:

`$(tsdir)/proj` has prerequisites `$(tsdir)/proja` and `$(tsdir)/projb`. I want `proja`'s and `projb`'s makefile to be called every time I have to build `proj`. If `proja` or `projb` are out of date and are updated, then their makefile will touch `$(tsdir)/proja` and `$(tsdir)/projb` respectively. If those files are then newer than `$(tsdir)/proj`, then rebuild proj.

I have this working by using the below code and the `FORCE` target. If I try and switch to use `.PHONY` targets, this doesn't work. I prefer `.PHONY` as that is supposedly the more 'correct' way of doing this. But it doesen't work and I don't know why. `proja`'s and `projb`'s makefiles aren't called with `.PHONY` targets, but `proj` is rebuilt.

I am using GNU make 3.81.

Thanks
Nachum

```
$(tsdir)/proj: $(tsdir)/proja $(tsdir)/projb
...

$(tsdir)/%: FORCE  
    make -C $(prereqdir)/$*

FORCE:

#or

$(tsdir)/proj: $(tsdir)/proja $(tsdir)/projb
...

.PHONY: $(addprefix $(tsdir)/, $(projects))

$(tsdir)/%:  
    make -C $(prereqdir)/$*
```

Comment: Shouldn't that _proj_ at the end of be in `I want proja's and projb's makefile to be called everytime I have to build proja`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.PHONY` targets are supposed to represent tasks, not real files, where implicit rule search works only for files. Thus, there is no way to build a phony target with an implicit rule.

From [Phony Targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) chapter:

> Since it knows that phony targets do not name actual files that could be remade from other files, `make` skips the implicit rule search for phony targets

In your case I would just use explicit rule, may be with a [static pattern](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
.PHONY: $(addprefix $(tsdir)/, $(projects))

$(addprefix $(tsdir)/, $(projects)) : $(tsdir)/% :  
    make -C $(prereqdir)/$*
```

Comment: First, thank you for that explanation.

I tried this, and now the problem is that the targets ($(tsdir)/proja,b) are now always considered to be new b/c this target is run. And so the recipe for $(tsdir)/proj is always run. And the actual $(tsdir)/proja,b are not updated, and so I would hope that the recipe for $(tsdir)/proj would not run.

Comment: Are `$(tsdir)/proj[a|b]` directories or regular files? In the former case using their timestamps is not a good idea, timestamp of a directory may change if for example a file is removed or a new one is created.

Comment: $(tsdir) is my timestamp directory, and /proj[a|b] are regular files. I do not have dependencies (except order-only ones) on directories, they are always on files.

Comment: Then I would split building into [two phases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10727593/545027). First, recurse into sub-directories to build subprojects (using phony rules), [see how](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11206700/545027). Second, build top-level artifacts with regular prerequisites on files that were updated in the fist phase.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you can get the result you want by adding a phony *dependency* to the (real) time-stamp files, one removed from the master project *proj*.

```
.PHONY: phony
phony: ; : $@

ts := $(addprefix $(tsdir)/, $(projects))

${ts} : $(tsdir)/%: phony
    make -C $(prereqdir)/$*

$(tsdir)/proj: $(tsdir)/proja $(tsdir)/projb
...
```